# Classic Academic Textbooks

Tags: compiler-theory

I'm familiar with both the *Wizard Book*:

[Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html)

and the *Dragon Book*:

[Compilers: Principles Techniques and Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book_%28computer_science%29)

However, I'm curious to find out which other classic academic textbooks people would consider **essential reading** for a programmer.

Comment: I for one would not consider the dragon book essential.

Comment: many similar questions are already asked.  Also, this should be CW to encourage people to upvote and downvote freely.

Comment: Do you maybe want to reference exact duplicate you marked the question as?  I couldn't find similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the word is "classic", then I'd say the collection from Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming".

Answer (score 2):

A must have 'Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software'

aka Gang Of Four

[http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1264576409&sr=8-6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)

Answer (score 2):

I would say the following is a classic!!

Brian Kernighan book on C Language

http://www.amazon.co.uk/C-Programming-Language-2nd/dp/0131103628/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1264614901&sr=8-1

It was the first book I had to learn programming!

Answer (score 1):

[Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Automata_Theory,_Languages,_and_Computation)

Also see:
 [ACM Classic Books Series](http://portal.acm.org/toc.cfm?id=SERIES11430&type=series&coll=ACM&dl=ACM)
This is a list of classic computer science books that was arrived as a result of the poll ACM conducted among its members.